# Envrionment variables in Cloud Run referencing the Google Cloud project id

Tags: environment-variables, google-cloud-run

Even though it was not documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#env-vars), I think the `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` environment variable used to be defined inside the container but it is not anymore

I can even find it referenced in code here:
[`project := os.Getenv("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT")`](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/konfig/blob/master/konfig.go#L314)

Where can I find my project id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we look at [Container instance metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#metadata-server), which is in the Cloud Run docs, we see an explicit reference to this being the mechanism to determine your own environment including Project Id and service accounts.

Comment: That's right, thank you!
I use metadata server to get my access token, I forgot about it to get my project id.
 The path is 'computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id'